# On Load Event , Selection change event fired, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing Country, State, City using jQuery Method,
but problem is when load event fired, also change() fired, and i am not able to load State dropdown

```
$("#SelectCountry").load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Member/Home.aspx/GetCountryName",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: "{'name': '" + "1" + "'}",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d != null) {
                $.each(response.d, function (i, response) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#SelectCountry").append("<option value=" + response.CountryId + ">" + response.CountryName + "</option>");
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {}
    });
}
$("#SelectCountry").change() {
    alert("Select event changed;");
}
```

Comment: If you format your code correctly, nice things will happen to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
$("#SelectCountry").load() { // doesn't compile
     ...
}
```

with

```
$("#SelectCountry").load( function() { // pass a callback to load
     ... // will be executed when loading finishes
});
```

But in your case, even while I don't see the HTML, I don't see why you want to use load. You should simply call the code that is inside the block.

Comment: i just want to show a script !, i am going to post on pastebin, thanks for reply

Comment: and writing this : http://pastebin.com/cYMNW3g8 , i am not able to fire a webmethod anymore